# Nichrome wire no heat

Tags: batteries

No heat from nichrome wire. I have tried various experiments on YouTube regarding foam cutters using nichrome wire or steel wire with 9V batteries with an on/off switch or no on/off switch.

When the steel wire didn't work, I tried using N80 30AWG nichrome wire. I connected the wires from the battery directly to the nichrome wire and no heat at all. I even tried connecting two 9V batteries. I only have a basic understanding of electricity but the simple DIY foam cutters on YouTube do not seem to be much of a challenge to create. Appreciate any help or other tests I can perform to confirm I am getting heat. Oh and the batteries are fully charged.

Comment: Dead battery, I would say.

Comment: Or you didn't properly strip the insulation on some wires.

Comment: How long a wire? Did your batteries get hot?

Comment: 9V battery is quite useless in this application. Try calculating the voltage needed.

Comment: Have you measured the resistance of your nichrome wire?

Comment: Up the voltage. V/R=I_load on nichrome. Observe safety precautions and use AC from mains. The current must flow.

Answer (score 2):

According to my quick ca. 2000 [test](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.electronics.design/6nEUtCCNMYY), a fresh Duracell 9V battery can briefly supply 5A of output current, so a couple ohms source resistance. Zinc-carbon batteries will not supply anything like that. **Do not** attempt with NiCd batteries, explosion can result.

That's more that sufficient to burn your fingers with even a small (eg. 10-20mm) length of wire. [This](https://wiretron.com/nichrome-resistance-wires/) set of tables should give some basic idea of how much current is required for a given free-air temperature.

It's around 7 ohms per foot (30cm) so the length needs to be perhaps in the 4" range to get up to >500°C.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate you are wasting your timewith 9v batteries, you should use a car battery or a basic battery charger with no electronics or if you can find a redundant transformer with about 12 volts and supply around 5  amps, or find someone with some electrical skills, you need a basic understanding of resistance, volts, and amps and how they relate to each other, (easy for me  tradie for 50 plus years)

Comment: I don't think that you mean a transformer... you mean a DC power supply..?